# Delegates in Haxe

Tags: haxe

Is there something like a delegate in Haxe?

This would come in handy when I use a anonymous function but still want to maintain the current class'es variable scope.

```
myObject.callback = function(param) { this.variable = param; };
```

As you can see `this` is not accessible from within the function body. :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know you can do it in [latest Haxe version](http://ncannasse.fr/blog/haxe_2.08). In earlier versions you should be able to do:

```
var t=this;
myObject.callback = function(param) { t.variable = param; };
```

Comment: Right, it works... and an update to 2.08 would pay in this case - thanks!